# Running 1080p video from within XOrg smoothly

Tags: performance, video, gpu, xorg

The 1080p examples that work outside of X.Org run very smoothly on my Pi, but within X.Org they don't run very smoothly at all at the moment.

Given that X.Org is currently not GPU-accelerated, this is understandable - but with the hardware limitations will running such video smoothly in X.Org ever be possible, or is this unlikely even if X.Org was running on the GPU?

Comment: @dunsmoreb Unnecessary and confusing edit.

Comment: @Jivings How is it confusing? It clarifies that the question is about X.Org.

Comment: @dunsmoreb The confusion was why you would bother to edit. It was pretty clear. X pretty universally means Xorg. Just retag next time.

Comment: This site will potentially have users that are not Linux experts or are even that experienced with Linux.  We should not assume a user will know what "X" means on this site.

Comment: `X` and `x.org` are not the same thing, by the way. X.org is the foundation that owns license on X. In fact, they specifically request only these names be used: `X`, `X Window System`, `X Version 11`, `X Window System, Version 11`, `X11`

Comment: @KyleMaceyJun The X.Org tag has been replaced with `xorg` with `X` as synonym.

Comment: once again, VLC could use openmax ;)

Comment: There are tons of X11 implementations. This question is probably very specific about the x.org one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need a video player that decodes the video using the GPU.

The suggested (and currently the only known) player for the RPi that does this is [OMXPlayer](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer#readme).

Comment: I love OMXPlayer! It runs so smoothly. Is it maintained?

Comment: @AlessandroCosentino: The activity on that GitHub repo is pretty recent, so I would think so.