# How can I install GStreamer gst-omx?

Tags: software-installation

Been having the toughest time over the last week trying to get gst-omx plugin working with gstreamer on the Raspberry PI.

I wonder if anyone here has done it and could show me how?

I've installed wheezy as `git://git.collabora.co.uk/git/user/gkiagia/gst-omx0.10-debian.git` needs a testing version of gstreamer.

Gstreamer is working fine on the raspberry using the normal plugins, so no hardware acceleration.

Once I install the gst-omx it comes up in the blacklist for gstreamer and I'm completely stuck as my linux knowledge is very limited so debugging is impossible for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate slightly? What doesn't work?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what you need this for? Perhaps there is a better alternative you could use.

Comment: All I need is a command line video/audio player. So that from inside my code I can call the code and point it towards a media file, let it play then return back to the code.
I think i have over complicated it and I should be trying to merge the hello_video with the hello_audio example.

I thought gstreamer would easier because its a framework instead of learning how to code OpenIL, but I dont think the framework is all there yet.

Comment: I think what you need to look at is this question! http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100/running-1080p-video-from-within-xorg-smoothly

Comment: The problem with omxplayer is that it takes a long time to load up a video, where as the hello_video example does it almost instantly. I will need to play lots of videos in quick succession one after the other, if I was to use omx player I would be having large gaps between files which wont work. This is why I'm looking to use gstreamer or somehow merge hello_audio and hello_video... Because ill be encoding the videos my self it will always be the same codec.

Comment: The problem is hat omxplayer is the only player that will decode video using the GPU. Other players will not have the same great, unchoppy playback.

Comment: We're discussing this issue in the Raspberry Pi forums: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=6852

Answer (score 9):

[Details from Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=6852&sid=d703ec764e398ee4218941360bff93bf)

#### Get and install  rpi-update if necessary

```
sudo wget http://goo.gl/1BOfJ -O /usr/bin/rpi-update && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update
sudo apt-get -y install git-core
```

#### Upgrade to the latest packages and firmware

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
```

#### Get gst-omx source from the raspberry branch

```
cd $HOME 
git clone -b 0.10 git://anongit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-omx
```

#### Install the Gstreamer packages, and the packages required to build omx

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf gtk-doc-tools libtool
```

#### Autogenerate the configure script, configure, make and install gst-omx

```
cd gst-omx
./autogen.sh --noconfigure
./configure --prefix=/home/pi/omx
make 
make install
```

#### Set up the gst-omx environment for the pi user

```
cp  omx/gstomx-raspberry.conf $HOME/omx/lib/gstreamer-0.10/gstomx.conf
cd $HOME
echo -e \\n# Gstreamer environment >> .profile
echo export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=$HOME/omx/lib/gstreamer-0.10/ >> .profile
echo export GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR=$HOME/omx/lib/gstreamer-0.10/ >> .profile
echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/omx/lib/gstreamer-0.10/ >> .profile
. ./.profile
```

#### Install the GStreamer Tools

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-tools
```

#### Verify that gst-omx has been installed correctly.

If it has the following command should show these plug-ins:

```
> gst-inspect-0.10 | grep omx
openmax  omxmpeg4videodec: OpenMAX MPEG4 Video Decoder
openmax  omxh264dec: OpenMAX H.264 Video Decoder
```

#### Problems with omxmpeg plug-ins being blacklisted

There's a conflict with omx and gstreamer-plugins-bad, so the following cleared the blacklisting:

```
sudo aptitude remove libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0
```

#### Enable omxh264enc plugin for hardware h.264 Encoding

This plugin, so far, appears to be broken, but here's how to enable it.
Add the following to $GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR/gstomx.conf

```
[omxh264enc]
type-name=GstOMXH264Enc
core-name=/opt/vc/lib/libopenmaxil.so
component-name=OMX.broadcom.video_encode
rank=256
in-port-index=200
out-port-index=201
hacks=no-empty-eos-buffer;no-component-role
```

Comment: According to an anon user, the git branch name has changed, so under *Get gst-omx source from the raspberry branch*, `git clone -b raspberry` should be `git clone -b 0.10`.  I did not confirm this.

Comment: How can I use gstreamer to send video to nginx-rtmp from the CSI Camera moudule??

Answer (score 4):

Add this repo line into `/etc/apt/sources.list`

> deb http://vontaene.de/raspbian-updates/ . main

Then simply ....

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```

*That 3rd party repository is hosted by a member off the [Pi forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=293634). They compile the latest versions of the gst-omx project and publish the files there.*

You can check if it recognised the Pi's hardware capabilities using this command

```
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep omx
```

[image]

Comment: As of now this the fastest and easiest method. Compiling like described below in Unkle George's answer didn't work for me as some depencyies were out of date.

Answer (score 4):

As of April 2015 Raspbian repositories include GStreamer 1.2 and the OpenMAX plugins, so the easiest way is [ppumkin's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10370/28920) but without editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```

then check with:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 | grep omx
```

Comment: I don't have `gstreamer1.0` in the repository. How do I add it?

Comment: There is no package gstreamer1.0 but apt-get should use it as a regular expression and download all gstreamer1.0... packages. Does `apt-cache search ^gstreamer1.0` show any packages ?

Comment: It does find gstreamer-related packages, I just thought there should be an actual `gstreamer1.0` deb package that included all the basic gstreamer packages.