# VLC Hardware acceleration

Tags: gpu, vlc

I'm new to Raspberry Pi. I am trying to develop a media player that would use a library like `libvlc` to do the decoding. Now the problem is that I can't get the hardware acceleration going...

I have read a lot on the internet and but no one seems to really know.

Has anyone got it working? Could you please share how?

**Solution**: I have successfully compiled VLC with hardware acceleration on Raspberry and posted a tutorial on my blog!
For all interested here's the link: [VLC hw on Pi tutorial](http://intensecode.blogspot.com/2013/10/tutorial-vlc-with-hardware-acceleration.html)

Comment: What is the question specifically? Have we got what working? there is allot of hardware acceleration for allot of various things. Allot of encoding/decoding is done using hardware, there is also OpenGLES.. What are you asking abooot?

Comment: The [omxplayer](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer) is a popular command line media player on the pi, and does support hardware acceleration. Maybe a starting point?

Comment: Adding to @Frepa's point. OMXPlayer is open source so should be useful to have a look at

Comment: This is great. H/W acceleration is the only reason I use omxplayer. Looks like I can ditch it now :)

Comment: @xiaobai my thoughts **exactly**

Comment: How did you install libfaac-dev as it is a dependancy, and the one I can't seem to install.

Comment: One small suggestion. You could post the solution here as an answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to learn about OpenGL ES used on Raspberry Pi [here is a interactive](https://github.com/benosteen/opengles-book-samples/tree/master/Raspi) walk through with examples.

You can find out more about OpenGL at [opengles-book](http://opengles-book.com/)

That can be useful for the GUI and at the moment you do not need X to run them (in some ways nice but in other not nice)

You would also need to implement hardware decoding video using the available (and if licensed options) spoken about on the [charities site.](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/1839)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [OpenElec](http://openelec.tv/). It's an open source media player distribution and works very well out of the box on a 256MB Model B RasPi, able to play media files from a USB key or over a network.

There are installation images (and source code) available from the website and there is a RasPi compatible image available by automatic download with [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) (multi-image bootloader). Very easy to configure and a makes a great starting point for development of either your own system or a module within OpenElec itself.

Comment: Does OpenElec support functions such as synchronizing video on mulitple nodes (raspis), audio visualizations and running in slave mode (ie. ssh in, or remotely issue commands to run on main screen)

Comment: I think there are some existing visualization modules and I suppose you could find / write modules/hacks for the rest. 

The main advantages are that it's configured as a HTPC straight out of the box and there are a lot of existing modules you can leverage