# Synchronizing video on multiple raspis

Tags: raspbian, networking, raspbmc, kodi, streaming-video

I would like to synchronize one feed (ie. this [super maly fight scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOVC4NY8Q-A) from Puss and Boots...lets assume I have it on disk and in `.h264`) across 3 raspis (via a network) each connected to one HD monitor for a total of 3 HD monitors. I can easily do this via mplayer as described [here](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/networksync.html) and via VLC as described [here](http://hackedexistence.com/project-vlc.html), but neither of those run on raspi in any useful way as they do not exploit hardware acceleration.

What are my options, either with [OMXplayer](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/) (Raspbian OS), [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/) (Raspbmc OS) or with [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) (XBMC OS)

Comment: Now people have added H/W video playback to vlc successfully: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/vlc-hardware-acceleration

Comment: @xiaobai when you said that, all I heard was a divine "aaaaaaaaa"

Comment: @xiaobai To anyone thinking of installing vlc, it is a major PITA. I have been at it for over 10 days and nights and the best I have gotten is to actually install the thing without it finding any codecs.

Comment: Can't you just use the compiled VLC binary this guy proivded? http://intensecode.blogspot.com/2013/10/tutorial-vlc-with-hardware-acceleration.html

Comment: @xiaobai I tried that and it **still** did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added synchronizing capabilities to omxplayer, you can checkout the repo [here](https://github.com/pukster/omxplayer-sync-2). Note this is still in development, however, to the best of my knowledge, it is the only way to get reliable synchronization across multiple raspis.

Answer (score 2):

`omxplayer` is not as nearly feature rich as `mplayer` or `vlc`. I don't believe the synchronization feature is internal to the current version of `omxplayer`. You may be able to achieve some level of synchronization between different stations with some manual methods as described below:

The current (github) version of `omxplayer` can be controlled through `dbus`. (The stock version from `raspbian wheezy` is an old version without this capability last time when I checked). So one approach might be writing a small program which 1) sits on the network receiving UDP commands from your controling device. then 2) sends appropriate dbus messages to the `omxplayer` process.

If you just want to do it quick and dirty, you can add your own UDP server thread in omxplayer, inject plain control messages (like `KeyConfig::ACTION_PAUSE`) directly to `OMXControl::getEvent()`.

In order to sync multiple raspi's in this way, you need to modify omxplayer source code to make the player pause in the verying beginning of the playback. Then your controlling device broadcasts a Pause command which make all omxplayers start to play at the same time. All later commands will be broadcasted to all Raspberry Pi's so they will remain synchronized.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this, and if I get it to work, I will post it as an answere here

Comment: So I have actually been busy looking for a solution to this (udp streaming, vlc for raspi, omxplayer-sync, and launching omxplayer at same time) and none have worked really. Going to try your suggestion here, but could you please address some of these issues: is there something wrong with the `dbus approach` or are paragraphs 2 and 3 part of same solution? Basically, are paragraphs 2,3 and 4 all different solutions?

Comment: Also, do you mean this version of omxplayer: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer

Comment: @puk nothing wrong with the dbus approach. It's just you need another small program to handle the inter-Pi UDP communication. Paragraph 2 & 3 are two solutions, and paragraph 4 applies to both.

Comment: I am against using anything when `omxplayer` is running. omxplayer-sync for example lags even on 720p https://github.com/turingmachine/omxplayer-sync

Answer (score 2):

There is a project I seen posted at [www.raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/3648) that was creating a video wall. The project page is at [www.piwall.co.uk](http://www.piwall.co.uk/). Might be useful, I have not tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://github.com/turingmachine/omxplayer-sync , it's synchronize multiples pi with unmodified omxplayer, only a python program.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it easily with Gstreamer and its fully supported. There are precompiled packages on Rasbpian that you can use.

From server, you could stream file with rtp. On clients you can just run simple playbin and that is it. All 3 in the same time.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Could you please provide some more, for example, what exactly is Gstreamer, are these 'precompiled packages' of gstreamer or synched omxplayer with gstreamer, what is rtp, what is playbin, and 'all 3' what? =)

Comment: Ah, welcome to beautiful world. As idea is somehow special, you should use special software - like Gstreamer. For start, I would suggest to install it on your PC and try to run `gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/user/your/movie.mp4`. Then, use google to find out that you can build various pipelines in command line. Pipelines can stream, play, convert or [you choose]. If you are using Raspbian on rpi, you can follow this link (http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=293634#p293634) for packages that support gstreamer-1.0 and playback without starting X.

Comment: And rtp is just a protocol that you have to use for network streaming of h264 file. You build rtp in pipeline (google it). By 'all 3' I meant all 3 of your rpis in network.

Comment: I didn't try gstreamer but I tried streaming from vlc (on a desktop) and it was disastrous, like watching the scrambled Adult channels in the early 90's. I came across a thread where someone had a similar problem, and it apparently had something to do with the memory constraints of the raspi. Can you possibly comment before I go invest yet another 100 hours of my life into a linux venture =) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found one potential solution, though it is not perfect. I have a [test script](https://github.com/pukster/omxplayer-sync-tests) up on git hub which tries to launch, in my case 2, threads, which each eventually call omxplayer on two different raspis. The program picks a time in the future to sychronize the launch of omxplayer, ie. (12:00:00 exactly, or 5 seconds from now), then a shell script waits as best it can and then, hopefully, the two raspis launch at the same time. Currently, 90% of the trials launch with less than 100ms difference between the two, however, the audio delay is still noticeable. I take this to mean that either the human ear is extremely sensitive, or launching `omxplayer` and playing the movie are two different things.

Also, I am assuming that once started, and with smooth playback, the two raspis will play the video at the same exact speed.

If you plan on playing audio from only a single source (ie. a home theater system), this solution should suffice.

**Warning:**

As is, the code has a bug whereby every 1 in a 100 times it just hangs.

Comment: This is **not** a good solution. Even when it works, after 30 minutes the drift will be noticeable