# How do I install libfaac-dev on Raspi?

Tags: raspbian, video

I have been at this for so long that no one short of [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) can tell me to RTFM.

I am trying to install VLC as per [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/vlc-hardware-acceleration) and [these instructions](http://intensecode.blogspot.ca/2013/10/tutorial-vlc-with-hardware-acceleration.html), but that installation requires several (read 'dozens') of modules, one of which in turn requires [libfaac-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libfaac-dev). Installing that should be relatively painless:

```
sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev
```

However, I get the following error

```
E: Unable to locate package libfaac-dev
```

Which, [turns out](https://superuser.com/questions/467774/how-to-install-libfaac-dev) is due to the `libfaac-dev` package being technically not free so it is in the 'multiverse' respositories. So all you have to do is edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and add a few repository addresses. But 'multiverse' is for Ubuntu, and Raspi runs on Debian 7.0 ("wheezy") so it uses a different system altogether (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27513/what-is-the-difference-between-debian-contrib-non-free-and-how-it-corresponds)).

At this point I had so many tabs open, and I was trying to install so many dependencies of dependencies that I hit a wall, so my questions are:

1. Is it possible to install libfaac-dev on Raspi?
2. If so, is it even necessary (ie. not already installed)?
3. If so, how do I install `libfaac-dev`?

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same problem except with the `libfame-dev` package.

Comment: See [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12887/how-to-install-libfame-dev-on-raspbian) for my related question.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by [Pouet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/17046/17420) *nearly* did it for me, but the following list took it all the way:

1. Edit your apt-get source list by adding another source.
   `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
   Paste in `deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy main non-free` on a new line. Save and exit.
2. `sudo apt-get install debian-keyring`
3. Next, we would perform `sudo apt-get update`, but it will complain that the public key for the new source is missing. You should probably go ahead and try it before continuing, because I would strongly recommend against blindly installing keys that you don't know what they are just because som random guy (me) told you so. `apt-get` will complain about key 07DC563D1F41B907 (which has fingerprint 1F41B907) is unknown.

   > The actions 4 and 5 need to be properly run as root (`sudo bash`, and then executing them), simply prepending every command with `sudo` did not do it for me.
4. `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1F41B907`
5. `gpg --armor --export 1F41B907 | apt-key add -`
6. `sudo apt-get update`
7. `sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev`

Comment: I found that `sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring` fixed the PGP key issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

`faac` is currently not available in the raspbian repos, you can easily build it yourself though:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/build && cd /tmp/build
$ apt-get -b source libfaac0 faac
```

`apt-get source` will leave you with three `.deb`-packages:

```
faac_1.28-6_armhf.deb
libfaac-dev_1.28-6_armhf.deb
libfaac0_1.28-6_armhf.deb
```

You will need to install all three packages, in the following order:

`$ sudo dpkg -i libfaac0_1.28-6_armhf.deb libfaac-dev_1.28-6_armhf.deb faac_1.28-6_armhf.deb`

Afterwards `faac` will be ready to use.

Edit: The `libfaac-dev_1.28-6_armhf.deb` might not be needed, I haven't tested it though. YMMV.

Comment: It needs "sudo apt-get install debhelper" for building.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to compile it yourself if it's not in the repositories and no one else is offering it.

```
apt-cache search aac | grep aac | grep dev
libaac-tactics-ocaml-dev - Coq tactics for reasoning modulo AC (devt files)
libaacs-dev - free-and-libre implementation of AACS (development files)
libvo-aacenc-dev - VisualOn AAC encoder library (development files)
libvoaacenc-ocaml-dev - OCaml interface to the vo-aacenc library -- developpement files
science-dataacquisition-dev - Debian Science data acquisition development packages
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there is a prebuilt package for arm, at least not according to the packages site: http://pkgs.org/download/libfaac-dev

What could do is try to download an build the source package. If the dependencies are met, it should be as easy as

```
$ apt-get -b source faac
$ sudo dpkg -i faac.deb
```

(I haven't tried, and the file name `faac.deb` might be different. You should find a deb package to install after you completed the first step, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I've followed this guy : http://raspi.tv/2012/get_iplayer-installation-on-raspberry-pi-with-debian-wheezy-beta and libfaac-dev was installed without any problem.

so : 
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy main non-free
sudo apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev