# How to install libfame-dev on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, debian, software-installation, packages

I am trying to install [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) backend on an Raspberry Pi. I began following [these instructions](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/User_Manual%3aInitial_Installation) to install from source but I quickly hit a roadblock:

```
pi@mythtvpi ~ $ sudo apt-get install <snip>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' instead of 'msttcorefonts'
Note, selecting 'libcdparanoia-dev' instead of 'libcdparanoia0-dev'
Note, selecting 'libfftw3-dev' instead of 'fftw3-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libfame-dev
```

Checking `/etc/apt/sources.list` I see:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

As I understand (I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to Linux), these are all the available sources for software, at least on `mirrordirector.raspbian.org`.

Is there some repository I can add to gain access to [`libfame-dev`](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/dists/testing/main/binary-ia64/package/libfame-dev)? Or do I need to build it from source too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have solved this by adding this to my *sources.list*:

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy main non-free
```

It now appears to have found the package.

I arrived at this solution by some googling and luck. I found [this site](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/) (which hosts the packages) and then did some more googling to figure out how to add that as a repository. I still get a warning:

```
W: GPG error: http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 07DC563D1F41B90
```

I imagine I need to add a key but not sure how yet, or where to get it from. Regardless, it seems to be installing now...

Comment: Has this solved your problem? If so, please mark which one it is by clicking on the green check-mark. We are trying to get this site's Q:A ratio and % answered up to par. Thanks!