# control omxplayer seeking with frame precision

Tags: python, video, media

I'd like to control omxplayer seeking with frame precision from an existing instance with python.

I have seen [this](https://github.com/KenT2/pyomxplayer/blob/master/pyomxplayer.py) that I think is the way to go: open via python `subprocess` an instance, have a keyboard polling loop and `echo`ing commands to the shell that is running the omxplayer instance.

Everything ok but I can not find the ability of frame-precision seeking.

Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

tldr; use VLC + <kbd>e</kbd>.

### Can not be done using omxplayer

I am kind of stating the obvious, but it looks like it cannot be done with omxplayer. [A quick search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=omxplayer%20keyboard%20shortcuts) results in the following [the keyboard shortcuts](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/06/playing-videos-on-the-raspberry-pi-command-line/) that are related but do not offer a solution.

```
Left Arrow  Seek -30
Right Arrow Seek +30
Down Arrow  Seek -600
Up Arrow    Seek +600
```

Also, starting up the process at a specific frame is not possible, because it is limited to precision in seconds.

```
Usage: omxplayer [OPTIONS] [FILE]
Options :
# omitted other options for brevity
-l / --pos  start position (in seconds)
```

---

### Can be done using VLC!

I just stumbled upon the topic [VLC Hardware acceleration](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/vlc-hardware-acceleration?rq=1) on this RP Exchange. This enables you to run VLC on your Raspberry Pi. Since VLC features frame-by-frame navigation ([since 2008](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=43198)) you are saved, [just press <kbd>e</kbd>](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100320143825AAG7lZo)!

#### Command line options

Just like omxplayer, there are also keyboard shortcuts available - and configurable at [command line startup](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) - for VLC but again only with seconds as time unit.

```
Jump sizes:
--extrashort-jump-size=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
Very short jump length, in seconds.

--short-jump-size=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
Short jump length, in seconds.

--medium-jump-size=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
Medium jump length, in seconds.

--long-jump-size=<integer [-2147483648 .. 2147483647]>
Long jump length, in seconds.
```

Since this doesn't really work, you could also start VLC `--start-time={x}` where `x` is the amount of milliseconds. This starts the video on the defined point in time.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this later, you can start omxplayer from any point with the -l command. While the help says seconds, internally it multiplies whatever you put in by 1000.0f. So if you want to specify a start of 10 milliseconds just  say -l 0.10