# Guidelines for video format in Raspberry Pi

Tags: video

I'm attending to start a multiprojection project, and I think Raspberry Pi fits really well in it. I need to read a video from the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) and project it. There will be some (four maybe) videos so I think I need one board for each projection and synchronize them.

For the video, I have to work with some guys that are in the field of video editing. They ask me the resolution, the frame rate, the format (encoding and container), and the maximum size of each video file.

For example:

> resolution of 768x576, 25 fps, [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC), file .avi that not exeed 4 GB

what is the best for Raspberry Pi? Do I have to follow some guidelines or best practice to get maximum performance (video must not glitter) for the platform?

PS.: I am using the 2012-10-28-wheezy-raspbian and an SD card with class 10 (for video)

(I'm totally new to this platform so please be patient and also trivial knowledge can help me.)

Comment: Your title mentions video encoding, but your content says you are asking about video decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's handled every video I've thrown at it with ease. However, there are a couple of points to consider:

- You must use a video player that [supports hardware decoding](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/100/40). I suggest [OMXPlayer](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer#readme).
- You can purchase an [MPEG-2](https://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/) and [vc-1](https://www.raspberrypi.com/vc-1-license-key/) license key from the Raspberry Pi store. These are proprietary formats that provide decoding capabilities DVD and Windows media (WMV and WTV).
- H.264 support is built in, which caters for most HD content you will use (mkv & mp4).

I hope this helps.

Comment: and what about a resolution / file size?

Comment: How do you use OMXPlayer? It is installed, but if I enter `osmxplayer file.mpg` just nothing happens. it just sais "have a  nice day :)"